# How can I pass dynamic values to Solr fields in a URL?

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

How can I pass dynamic values to Solr fields in a URL?

Example:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/searching/select?q=*:*&fq=maths:25 AND science: 30
```

The 25 and 30 are dynamic values. How can I pass them as part of a Solr URL?

Comment: If you ask a question, please make it a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be what are you looking for is what in Solr is called [Parameter Dereferencing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Local+Parameters+in+Queries#LocalParametersinQueries-ParameterDereferencing). 
Parameter dereferencing lets you use the value of another argument rather than specifying it directly. This can be used in conjunction with `solrconfig.xml` simplifying the query call.

For example instead to write:

```
.../select?q=*:*&fq=maths:25 AND science:30
```

you can write:

```
.../select?q=*:*&fq={!qf=maths v=$q1}&fq={!qf=science v=$q2}&q1=25&q2=30
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want sum the parameters at query time. But anyway take a look at function queries: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries

Comment: Hi sir.. can i give like this..                                              http://localhost:8983/solr/searching/select?q=*:*&fq={!qf=maths v=$q1}&fq={!qf=science v=$q2}&q1=25&q2=30&fl=sum(q1,q2) asc

Comment: I don't understand the `asc` parameter at end of your query, do you want sort for the result of the output of function sum(q1,q2) ? In case you want, the correct syntax is `&sort=sum(q1,q2) asc`

Answer (score 1):

In suggest, you need to define exactly what concrete fields you want to search. You can't search in all dynamic fields by using wildcards in a field name in queries.

or

You can try this way

-copy the dynamic field into other destination field
-query that destination field

something like this

```
<copyField source="dynamicfieldname_*" dest="dest_fieldname"/>
```

Now you can query solr with that field name like

```
select?q=dest_fieldname:"25"
```

Comment: My url  :  http://192.168.30.20:8983/solr/#/searching/query. I have four fields id, maths, science, physics. In maths and science can i pass dynamic values like 2 , 3 or 4, 5 like that is it possible in solr. Please help me.

Comment: Try that way copy all four field to one common field using <copyField source="field1" dest="union"/> and <copyField source="field12" dest="union"/> same for other two fields. and use dest field name union to query with. /select?a=union:"querystring"

Comment: you can pass any integer if maths and science fields types are defined to take integer values. can you post your schema file

Comment: Hi sir, can you give url example like field : 25 and field2 : 30

Comment: /select?q=maths:"2"  change handlers as per your URL may for you it may goes like  192.168.30.20:8983/solr/#/searching/query?q=maths:"2"

Comment: http://192.168.30.20:8983/solr/searching/select?q=maths : 2&wt=json&indent=true. Acutally i integrate  postgresql with solr and i need to pass dynamic values for any two fields and sum the two fields value. Please help me.

Comment: you have to send request with every dynamic value. I mean if value changes then for every value you need to send request to solr.

Comment: how can i pass these values in solr. Currently i have some data in solr. I need to give dynamically values like maths : 75 and science :100 is present based on it i'm displaying data but i need pass values like maths :2 and science : 3 and sum(maths, science) in solr.

Comment: you mean you want change data in solr index. say field maths has 75 and field science has 100. you want to change those field values dynamically, is that what you are asking for.  ?

Comment: {"id":"yourdocID",
 "maths":{"set":99},
 "science":{"set":20}
}  [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents]  and remember partial document possible only if you are using only Solr4.0 +